# Doctrine ODM GridFS store resource

Tags: doctrine-orm, gridfs, odm

I'd like to know if there is a way to directly store a PHP resource in Doctrine ODM, something like :

```
$document->setFile($resource);
```

Or if first have to write it to a temporary file and then use it in `setFile()`.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used GridFS much, but looking at the code you could create instance of `GridFSFile` in your setter without providing constructor argument and later call [`->setBytes()`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/blob/49433f0e4f9cb00f49a73e579bb36e32e348ebd6/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/GridFSFile.php#L104) method to set what is to be written.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, but I think that `setBytes` is meant to receive a file path, while `setFile()` is the one used to store a resource, which is not implemented by the Doctrine GridFSFile, and I cant do something like `$gf->setBytes(stream_get_content($resource))` because I'm low on memory :/